# Menu control .ascx label access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a control used by multiple web pages. In this control I'm running a stored proc to get a user's permission level. I then store this in an invisible label. 
In the pages that this menu control is loaded in different things happen based on the permission level, mostly buttons being enabled/disabled. 
My question is can I access the label I've put in the menu control (.ascx) from the VB of the pages it's in? and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways.
Say your label is this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPermission" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

1: You can get the VALUE of the label like.

```
Public ReadOnly Property Permission As String
     Get
         Return lblPermission.Text
     End Get
 End Property
```

2: Get the LABEL itself like:

```
 Public ReadOnly Property LblPermission As Label
     Get
         Return lblPermission
     End Get
 End Property
```

3: Find the lable inside the UC (MyMenuUC1 below) is the id of the menu usercontrol:

```
Dim lblPermission As Label = CType(MyMenuUC1.FindControl("lblPermission"),Label)
```

4: Grab string like this:

```
Dim permission As String = CType(MyMenuUC1.FindControl("lblPermission"),Label).Text
```

Comment: Excellent! could I also just grab the straight up value using:
`Dim permission As String = CType(MyMenuUC1.FindControl("lblPermission").Text,Label)`

Comment: Try #4. Updated answer above.